# Три колонки. Централ посередине

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Имеется интересное задание.

```
<div class="slider">
   <div class="1s">1st slide</div>
   <div class="2s">2nd slide</div>
   <div class="3s">3d slide</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.1s {
float: left;
}

.2s {
margin: 0 auto;
}

.3s {
float: right;
}

.slider div {
width: 200px;
}
```

Суть проблемы: 1й div выравнивать по левой стороне, 3й - по правой, а центральный по центру. Текст в каждом блоке выравнивается по левой стороне. Центральный блок имеет минимальный отступ 150 пикселей от обоих блоков.

У меня получается в этом способе, что 3 слайд сползает вниз, не могу придумать, как сделать его inline

Comment: А в чем причина?

Comment: он резиновый. Второй блок всегда должен быть по центру и при сужении быть иметь минимальный отступ 150 пикселей

Comment: А размеры первого и третьего какие? Мало инфы.

Comment: поправил немного условие, чтобы было понятнее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как я флоатами ничо не делаю, представляю свое решение:

```
  .slider {
    position:relative;
    }
    .s1 {
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    }
    .s2 {
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    }
    .s3 {
    padding: 0 215px;
    }
```

Comment: все хорошо, только если мне надо, чтобы и центральная колонка была 200 пикселей шириной?

Comment: Хм, тогда какая это резина?

Comment: 1й и 3й слайды крепятся к левой и правой границе, а 2й слайд всегда посередине. Но я впринципе додумал решение, с вашей наводкой, спасибо.